# Why Helmert coding in R divides subsequent differences

Tags: linear-model, contrasts

This question is about a weird behavior of Helmert coding  in `R` as implemented in the standard `contr.helmert` function.

First of all, it seems that `contr.helmert` in `R` implements what more often is called reversed Helmert coding, but that is fine. The problem is that it seems that subsequent regression coefficients get divided by $1, 2, \ldots, n$ where $n$ is the number contrast vectors including the intercept.

The code below shows what the problem is about.

```
m <- lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, contrasts = list(Species = "contr.helmert"))
coef(m)

(Intercept)    Species1    Species2 
5.8433333      0.4650000   0.3723333
```

Let us also calculate group means

```
(M <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean))

setosa versicolor  virginica
 5.006      5.936      6.588
```

Now, the intercept is correct and is equal to the mean of cell means. However, the first regression coefficient is equal not to:

$$
\text{versicolor} - \text{setosa} = 5.936 - 5.006 = 9.30
$$

but to:

$$
\frac{\text{versicolor} - \text{setosa}}{2} = 0.930 / 2 = 0.465
$$

Similarly, the second coefficient should be equal to:

```
M[3] - mean(M[1:2])

virginica 
    1.117
```

But is equal to

```
 (M[3] - mean(M[1:2])) / 3

 virginica
 0.3723333
```

Is there any justification for this weird behavior or is it a bug?

I checked that if you define a Helmert coding matrix by hand to give proper estimates
then it is still orthogonal, so orthogonality cannot be the answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been that way since before R existed, so you can be reasonably confident it isn't a bug. For an authoritative source, the definition is given in chapter 2 of *Statistical Models in S*, by Chambers & Hastie.

According to *Annotated Readings in the History of Statistics* by David and Edwards, Helmert (1876) actually defined the transformation

$$t_n  = (j(j+1)^{-1/2}(j\epsilon_j-\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2-\cdots-\epsilon_{j-1})$$

in order to derive, basically, the $\chi^2$ distribution. The scaling is not the same as either the S version or the 'proper' version.

[Lancaster](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312989) (1965) wrote about Helmert matrices 'in the strict sense' as being the same as Helmert's definition. He is clearly talking about their use *as contrasts*. In terms  of the S contrast matrix, the columns would be rescaled to unit norm rather than to have 1 as the largest element.

All the sources I have found that use the S version and have a citation cite Chambers & Hastie -- eg the NAG Fortran [`lm_design_matrix`](https://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl26.0/html/g22/g22ycf.html) routine

It looks like the two current definitions of Helmert contrasts diverged from Helmert's definition some time between 1965 and 1990, but I don't know any more than that.  If I had to guess, it would that someone in the past who was interested primarily in *testing* contrasts (where the scaling is irrelevant) thought the integer-only version gave simpler hand computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thorough answer!